# Where to set a tag on banner with a text container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have made [this banner](http://vouzalis.dk/stack.html). The image has to link to another page, and the button to the same place.

I have set an `a href="#"` tag on the images. But the result is that the text inside the text container is not clickable. How can I make all the banner to a link? The text on the banner should not get an underline, but stay like a normal white text. Is that `text-decoration:none` I should use on the `a href` tag?

```css
  body {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }

  /* Set width between grid elements */
  
  .small-padding.top {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  
  .small-padding.bottom {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .small-padding.left {
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  
  .small-padding.right {
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
  
  .margin_bottom {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .row [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  
  .row {
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
  }
  
  .img-responsive {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  /* Position of buttons/text in a single grid element */
  
  .inner-wrapper {
    background: none;
  }
  
  .centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  
  .bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 6%;
  }
/* Position text on full width banner */
  .header-container {
    color: white;
    margin: 0 5%;
  }
  .banner-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16%;
    left: 6%;
  }
  
  /* Color on text */
  
  .dark-font {
    color: #333;
  }
  
  .light-font {
    color: #fff;
  }
   
  /* Set full width on columns */
  
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .img-responsive {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    /* Maybe delete btn-success: */
    .btn-success {
      width: fit-content;
    }
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    h3 {
      font-size: 1.2em;
    }
  }
  .image-overlay {
    position:relative;
  }
  .overlay {
    position:absolute;
    transition:all .3s ease;
    opacity:0;
    transition:1.9s;
    background: #00b1bab8;
  }
  .image-overlay:hover .overlay {
    opacity:1;
  }
  .overlayFade {
    background: rgba(27, 27, 27, 0.5);
    top: 0;
    /* Like this */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Working template</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
            <div class="image-overlay">
                <a href="#">
                    <picture>
                        <div class="overlay overlayFade"></div>
                        <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/1024.jpg">
                        <source media="(min-width: 380px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/380.jpg">
                        <img src="http://vouzalis.dk/1024.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:100%;">
                    </picture>

                    <div class="inner-wrapper banner-text">
                        <div class="header-container">
                            <h2 class="light-font">Here is headline 1</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                               tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Our Services</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This behavior is due to the HTML spec disallowing [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/content-models.html#interactive-content) in an anchor element: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element  "**Content model:**
Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant." Make your nested anchors spans and style accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you have time to show me an example on how to do this. I do not quite get it :-/

Comment: Sure.  For your code it should be pretty simple.  Just change the `<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Our Services</a>` to `<span class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Our Services</span>`. 
 The link still works, the styles look OK, and it's valid HTML. 
 See a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/qdLmb8u1.  Note that I changed the href to `href="/"` in the demo so you can see it navigating.  Clicking the image or the button should show a 404 page.

Comment: Just perfect. Thank you. Please lay an answer, so I can accept

Comment: Thanks, but that's OK.  I've already marked the question as a duplicate.  This consolidates searches for related issues to one answer that adequately explains the root problem.  Your question is a valuable addition to the site because it may index this issue better in search engines, but there's no need to provide an answer here because the linked answer already addresses the issue.  Leaving the question without a marked answer will not negatively affect you, so it works out for everyone to just leave it marked as a duplicate.  Glad I was able to help, though. :)

Comment: Ok thank you a lot for your help.